# Laravel - carbon for expiring posts

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

So in this project I have to make posts expire after seven days. I have this code in my `HomeController` and right now it shows me all posts made today on my homepage:

```
...
public function index()
    {

        $date = Carbon::now();
        $date->format("Y-m-d");
        $posts = Post::where('status','=', 1)->whereDate('created_at','=', $date)->get();
        return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }
...
```

So it shows me all posts made today with status 1 and that is okay. But I need to show me that posts not only for one day but for seven days and after it expires it needs to delete automatically. How can I solve this? Please help! Thank you!

EDITED

I tried with:

```
...
public function index()
    {

        $current = Carbon::now();
        $date = $current->addDays(7);
        $date->format("Y-m-d");
        $posts = Post::where('status','=', 1)->whereDate('created_at','=', $date)->get();
        return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }
...
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Using Carbon you can easily subtract days like this:

```
$posts = Post::where('status', 1)
           ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(7))
           ->get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post->delete();
}
```

You are basically comparing the current date and removing 7 days from now.
After that you get a posts collection and delete everything.

You may want to built the remove logic in the background so that the system check every day/days if it is time to remove it. For this you need to create a [Cronjob](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or a [Task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling).

With that you can for instance create something like this easily:

```
$schedule->job(new PostRemoveProcess, 'postsremove')->everyWeek();
```

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs) regarding this, it explain it really good.

Comment: But I don't want to remove 7 days from now. I want do add 7 days to my posts, it needs to show for 7 days and after that do be automatically deleted. With my current code posts are showing at day created only, I need it to show for 7 days, do you understand?

Comment: Needs the remove process be done in the background?

Comment: Okay I added your code ```Carbon::now()->addDays(7)``` but now nothing shows on my homepage

Comment: Yes so no error occur, in runs the function and remove the model. I updated my answer if you want to run the logic in the background as a cronjob, I am not an expert in cronjob so you should most likely read through the documentation and try it out:)

Comment: I updated date and time on my PC to 2020/01/19 to see if it deletes my posts after 7 days but nothing happens. I will try with Task. Thank you